# What are other examples of pivotal non-spherical categories?

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory, examples-counterexamples, hopf-algebras, fusion-categories

Apparently, an example of a pivotal non-spherical category can be found in the world of Hopf algebras/representation theory:

- Let $(H, \omega)$ be a pivotal non-spherical Hopf algebra with pivot $\omega$ (see *From Hopf algebras to tensor categories* by Andruskiewitsch et al. for an example). Then the action of the pivot $\omega$ endows the category of finite-dimensional $H$-modules with a pivotal non-spherical structure.

What other examples of pivotal non-spherical categories are known?
In particular, I am interested in examples where the category is even a fusion category.

Comment: Example 4.59 of Tubbenhauer's "Quantum topology without topology" might be of interest?

Comment: Thank you! The category you refer to is the one having as objects the elements of the group $\mathbb{Z} /3 \mathbb{Z}$ and complex multiples of identity morphisms as morphisms. The monoidal product is given by group multiplication (i.e. on morphisms $\gamma id_g \otimes \lambda id_h=id_{\lambda \gamma \cdot gh}$). The monoidal unit is the neutral element. One can define an associator and unitors using a 3 cocycle of $\mathbb{Z} /3 \mathbb{Z}$. This monoidal category is rigid (group inverse). Your reference seems to give an example of a pivotal structure on this category that is not spherical.